# Sickbeard API parsing using GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

Using `Gson` on Android, how should I set my Java classes to parse a `JSON` like this (from [Sickbeard API](http://sickbeard.com/api/#showseasons)):

```
{
"data": {
    "1": {
        "airdate": "2011-09-04", 
        "name": "Something Wicked This Fae Comes", 
        "quality": "HD TV", 
        "status": "Downloaded"
    }, 
    "2": {
        "airdate": "2011-09-11", 
        "name": "I Fought the Fae (And the Fae Won)", 
        "quality": "N/A", 
        "status": "Wanted"
    }, 
    "3": {
        "airdate": "2011-09-18", 
        "name": "Scream a Little Dream", 
        "quality": "N/A", 
        "status": "Unaired"
    }, 
    "4": {
        "airdate": "2011-09-25", 
        "name": "Episode 4", 
        "quality": "N/A", 
        "status": "Unaired"
    }, 
    "5": {
        "airdate": "", 
        "name": "Episode 5", 
        "quality": "N/A", 
        "status": "Skipped"
    }
}, 
"message": "", 
"result": "success"
}
```

These "1", "2", etc could be a number from 0 to whatever (and it may even be a "specials").

Comment: I Would suggest you to use a `HashMap<Integer, MyObject>` with `MyObject` containing your `airdate, name, ...`

Comment: Could you explain this better? If you write the answer I can accept it.

Comment: I'd like to add that I'm using Retrofit, so, if possible, show a solution that only modify the GSON object, to mantain Retrofit automatic parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes should look like this

**class Response**

```
@Expose @SerializedName("data")
private HashMap<Integer, DataObject> dataList;

@Expose @SerializedName("message")
private String message;

@Expose @SerializedName("result")
private String result;
```

**class DataObject**

```
@Expose @SerializedName("airdate")
private String airdate;

@Expose @SerializedName("name")
private String name;

... //other objects
```

And getter and setter and so on, now you should be able to parse it. But if you have the possibility to change the api I would suggest you to change the data List to a real json List of objects!!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the API. Thank you.